# How do I convert a decimal to hexadecimal using Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, base-conversion

I've been working on a calculator and I wanted to implement conversions from decimal to octal and from decimal to hexadecimal. I'm new to Xcode and Objective C, but I've managed to get a conversion from decimal to octal, it just doesn't seem to work with hexadecimal.

Here's the code I've written to convert a double to octal:

```
double result = 0;
...
double decToOct = [self popOperand];
NSString *oct = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%llo", (long long)decToOct];
result = [oct doubleValue];
```

Using the same scheme (obviously that includes changing `@"%llo"` with `@"%llx"`) the conversion to hexadecimal works up to a certain point. It does numbers 0 through 9 just fine, but once it hits 10, it comes up as 0. To test, I also input 5395 and it displayed 1513, the desired result.

Because of this, I can only assume that for some reason my code does not want to input the actual letters of the hexadecimal values (e.g. 11 would convert to B but it shows up as 0) .

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**
In addition, I have also been using this to display the `result`:

```
double result = [self.brain performOperation:operation];
self.display.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", result];
```

`result`, as listed from the top, is an argument which is eventually returned here, to `self.brain performOperation:operation`. This is supposed to handle the display of all operations, including: addition, multiplication, etc. but also octal and hexadecimal. Again, it works fine with octal, but not with hexadecimal.

Comment: Your format string needs to be @"%llx" not @"llx". With that correction, it works fine for me. If I input 1023, I get 3ff ( in a log of oct). When you say shows up as 0, do you mean a log of oct, or of oct.doubleValue?

Comment: @rdelmar Oops, my bad, I forgot to add the modulus character in here. I do in fact have it within my code already. And when it shows up as 0, I mean when I enter a number into the calculator and then hit "Hex", it simply shows up as 0. This is not the case when I hit the "Oct" button, it instead converts it correctly. This entire piece of code is part of a function which determines which button was pressed and returns the result depending on which operation you wanted to be performed. It uses a stack and pops each argument off to perform the calculation.

Comment: I think the problem is that "result" comes from [hex doubleValue]. Is that what you're doing? Any letters in your hex string will be ignored when doubleValue tries to convert the string to a double.

Answer (score 3):

Try this, May be it will help you. Please do let me know if i am wrong here:--->

```
NSString *decStr = @"11";
NSString *hexStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lX",
                 (unsigned long)[dec integerValue]];
NSLog(@"%@", hexStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know your string only contains a valid decimal number then the simplest way would be:

```
NSString *dec = @"254";
NSString *hex = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0x%lX", 
              (unsigned long)[dec integerValue]];
NSLog(@"%@", hex);
```